# Changing for loop to while loop crashes javascript webpage?

Tags: javascript

New to JS. I'm trying to change my for loop to a while loop. It prints the factors of a number, but for some reason, the while loops causes the webpage to stop responding. Any help is appreciated.

```js
var num, i = 1,
  array = [];

num = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number:"));

while (i < num) {
  if (num % i == 0) {
    array.push(i);
    i++;
  }

}
alert("The factors of " + num + " are: " + array + " and " + num);
```

Comment: You might wanna give `num` a value if the prompt did not return a numeric value or not a value at all, you might end up with `NaN` which would also fall into the case of `i < num` returning `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the incrementation of `i` variable outside the `if` condition. Else - the `while` loop will be stuck when the `num` is not divisible by specified `i`.

For example - if `num` is 5 and `i` is 2, the loop will be stuck because the `if` condition is not fulfilled - that's why `i` won't be incremented - and then we will experience an infinite loop.

```js
var num, i = 1, array = [];
num = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number:"));

while (i < num) { 
   if (num % i == 0) {
      array.push(i);
   }
   i++;
}
alert("The factors of " + num + " are: " + array + " and " + num);
```

Comment: so simple xd. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You increment `i` only if the condition of the "if" block is true. If that condition evaluates to false, `i` can't be incremented, and therefore the loop never ends.

```
if (num % i == 0) {  // <some value except 0> % 1 == 0 -> false
    array.push(i);
    i++;
}
```

so try:

```
while (i < num) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    i++; // now i can be incremented regardless of the condition in the "if" block.
}
```